# How to group the object in coreldraw 2020

Tags: corel-draw

Im using the current release **2020** version. I have my artwork place in center of the page, Ungroup once (ctrl+u) , And move the text little, When trying to group, The option is inactive, How can i group. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

**Note : When i group all it split all the object to individual then the option is active. That i dont want. I just want to ungroup once and move text and group it.**

[image]

Comment: I'm not a CorelDraw user, but it looks like that may not be a normal group. Perhaps check to see if there is a clipping mask. You may need to release it.

Comment: @BillyKerr. In the lower version i can group and ungroup goodway. Will thats not with 2020 version. Once i ungroup why i cant ungroup back. What is missing.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand the problem. :o( The animation runs too fast to see.

But probably you can try to edit the text without ungrouping, pressing Ctrl and Clicking on the object you need to interact with.

To group things, you could also use Ctrl+G.

Sometimes what I do is cutting some subgroups and pasting them on a new layer to organize them.

Perhaps you can edit your original question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Other than edit text i want to add some extra object and text and trying to group. The option is inactive. No Ctrl+G option active. Ungroup and ungroup is active. If your interested i can send the file.